# Primefaces one datatable filter for two tables

Tags: java, primefaces, filter, datatables

I have a table that is embedded in another table. I need to make a filter that works for both tables. Now search for only occurs on the first nested table does not affect

[My Code](https://gist.github.com/VitalyShkurenko/06f261fd5a4350a64599)

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible client-side. I would use the input from search field to filter your list which populates the dataTables manually (in the backing bean) and then update your table afterwards.